# Combine data from two separate file that have some common columns

Tags: python

Hi I have two files as shown below..and I want to have a third file from these two file. I could do it, but the code is really slow...

**file1**

```
1   469 -   CG  17  19
1   471 -   CG  19  19
1   483 +   CG  1   1
1   484 -   CG  20  23
1   488 +   CG  2   2
```

**file2**

```
1   468 +   CG  5   6
1   469 -   CG  25  31
1   470 +   CG  4   6
1   471 -   CG  22  31
1   483 +   CG  10  10
1   484 -   CG  36  43
```

**file3**

```
1   468 0   0   5   6
1   469 17  19  25  31
1   470 0   0   4   6
1   471 19  19  22  31
1   483 1   1   10  10
1   484 20  23  36  43
1   488 2   2   12  12
```

I am looking for a faster way to do it in python as the files are really big..

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you have now.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? How is the third file generated from file1 and file2?

Comment: I want to get file 3 (as shown above) as my output file...

Answer (score 1):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is a wonderful general-purpose toolbox for data set manipulation. It includes high-performance join operations. Here's how its file merge might look:

```py
import pandas as pd

def split_45(df):
    """
    Given a DataFrame, split column 4, which will contain
    an oddball tab-separated set of values from an otherwise
    fixed-width, space-separated dataset, into proper columns
    4 and 5.
    """
    tabcol = df[4].str.split("\t")
    df[4] = tabcol.apply(lambda x: x[0])
    df[5] = tabcol.apply(lambda x: x[1])


# read in datasets
d1 = pd.read_fwf("file1.txt", header=None)
d2 = pd.read_fwf("file2.txt", header=None)

# clean up the funky column 4 into 4 and 5
split_45(d1)
split_45(d2)

# delete undesired columns
del d1[2]
del d1[3]
del d2[2]
del d2[3]

# merge datasets, on the key field, unioning the keys (outer join),
# and sorting the results
d3 = pd.merge(left=d2, right=d1, on=[1], how='outer', sort=True)

# drop an unneeded column and fill the NaNs with 0
del d3['0_y']
d3.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# write fixed width text data to file
with open("file3.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(d3.to_string(header=False, index=False))
```

This code is longer than it would otherwise be, as your data does not seem to be pure fixed-width format, but includes some tabs separating the final columns. The `split_45` function is there just to clean those up and split those values into separate columns.

At the end of the run, `file3.txt` will contain:

```
 0  468   0   0   5   6
 1  469  17  19  25  31
 0  470   0   0   4   6
 1  471  19  19  22  31
 1  483   1   1  10  10
 1  484  20  23  36  43
 1  488   2   2   0   0
```

Note that this differs slightly from your desired output in the very last line. OTOH, the input above does not contain the `12 12` values for key `488`, so `2 2 0 0` is the correct result, given that input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')

file1Dict = {i[1]: [i[4], i[5]] for i in [line.split() for line in file1.read().splitlines()]}
file2Dict = {i[1]: [i[4], i[5]] for i in [line.split() for line in file2.read().splitlines()]}

for key in sorted(list(set(file1Dict) | set(file2Dict))):
    file1Value = file1Dict[key] if key in file1Dict else ['0', '0']
    file2Value = file2Dict[key] if key in file2Dict else ['0', '0']
    print ' '.join(['1', key] + file1Value + file2Value)
```

Output:

```
1 468 0 0 5 6
1 469 17 19 25 31
1 470 0 0 4 6
1 471 19 19 22 31
1 483 1 1 10 10
1 484 20 23 36 43
1 488 2 2 12 12
1 489 25 25 43 46
1 492 2 2 11 13
1 493 22 27 41 47
1 496 4 4 17 18
1 497 26 30 41 44
1 524 5 6 21 21
1 525 25 27 33 33
1 541 9 11 31 31
1 542 24 26 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks Srekcahrai ..but how have you known the other numbers in file 1 and 2???.when  I have only posted first few lines of the file..

Comment: You posted it earlier.

Comment: Hey Srekcahrai can you please tell me what is ....for key in sorted(list(set(file1Dict) | set(file2Dict)), key=lambda x: x) doing

Comment: set(file1Dict) | set(file2Dict) gives the 'OR' set of file1Dict and file2Dict keys. I have excluded key=lambda x: x. It was an accidental additional code, it was used to sort item.